# Java Code optimization : if else to resolve PMD complexity 24 to 0

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization, switch-statement, cyclomatic-complexity

I have string of array with size already defined  and i have to iterate though this array and fill it with fields value of someObject I have  . If i do this with if elseif elseif  or switch case i get high complexity   .. please kindly suggest proper way to do this

[image]

Comment: Why have you included your code as an image? Also why are you using a for loop here?

Comment: It would be better if you post your code as text instead of image

Comment: Why don't you hard code numbers in place of i like `value[0] = bean,getEmployeeI();` (do it for other values also) and remove for loop.

Comment: i tried , I am not able to post the code as error prevents me to post so some how i  find way to post my question ,

Comment: When you edit your question there is `?` icon, you can click on it. You will examples.

Comment: Add a `toArray()` to your 'bean'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a map to keep the mapping like this:

```
  private static final Map<Integer, String> MAP_VALUES = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  private static Map<Integer, String> getMapValues(Employe employe){
    if(MAP_VALUES.isEmpty()){
      MAP_VALUES.put(0, employe.getEmployeeI());
      MAP_VALUES.put(1, employe.getEmployeeLastName());
      MAP_VALUES.put(2, employe.getEmployeeDivision());
      ....
    }
    return MAP_VALUES;
  }

  public String getValueForEmploye(Employe employe){
    String[] value = ...;
    for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
      value[i] = getMapValues(employe).get(i); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: @namangala's comment is the right solution. There is no reason to use a loop, and the Map mechanism is harmful overhead.The PMD complexity is a misleading indicator as it didn't spot that this construct added inefficiency.